# Transcieving 125khz rf signal

Tags: transfer-function, data

Does anybody know if it is possible to connect a coaxial cable to the tx rx pins on a wireless module ? I am trying to send data via coaxial RG58 cable. Or would a twisted pair be more suitable? I would prefer coax over twisted pair. I am trying to send 125khz signal via low power air wakeup receiver, via coax to a 125khz bandpass filter, then to a 5 watt amplifier which then goes to a loop antenna resonating between 10khz-140khz which would then send data to a rfid tag which in turn will send back data to be transmitted back to the low power wake up receiver? All running at 50 ohms.

Comment: Possible? Probably. Ideal? No. You'll have to use coax obviously.

Comment: 125 kHz is barely RF (radio frequency), unless you have a rather large transmit antenna, it's not a radiating wave. Is this really radio, or more something inductively coupled like RFID? Or is 125 kHz just the message signal bandwidth, not the carrier?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is for passive keyless entry systems. The antenna I am using is a 1x1 meter loop antenna which i am using to excite key/tag from 6-8 meters away.

Comment: How would you actually connect a coax to the pins? Would you have a wire from the center core wire of coaxile straight to the rx tx pins? Does the braided wire need connecting?

Comment: I know bare minimal about electronics or wireless rf so any help will be appreciated